# Find filtration and distribution for function of Wiener process

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, brownian-motion, martingales

We have a process $Z_t = \frac{W_t}{t}$ on $t \geq 1$. We have to find filtration for which this process is a maritngale and find the distribution of the $\sup_{t \geq 1} Z_t$

I tried to do something with Ito formula. Let's define $f(t,x) = \frac{W_t}{t}$. Then we can say (after some calculation) that:

$Z_t = - \int_0^t \frac{W_u}{u^2}du + \int_0^t \frac{1}{u} dW_u$

But I do not have any idea what I can do with this result.

Comment: It might well be that $(Z_t)_t$ is a **backward** martingale, but it is certainly not a martingale. If $(Z_t)_{t \geq 0}$ was a martingale with respect to some filtration $(\mathcal{G}_t)_{t \geq 0}$ this would imply (by the tower property of conditional expectation) that $(Z_t)_{t \geq 0}$ is a martingal with respect to its canonical filtration... which it is clearly not.